# Как в WordPress разрешить выводить спецсимволы в url поста?

Tags: wordpress

Как в URL поста (permalink) разрешить вывод таких спецсимволов как **? = .** (знак вопроса, равно и точку). При попытке в посте задать ссылку вида **news.php?id=1234** движок убирает/изменят её до вида **news-phpid1234**, т.е. заменят точку на тире и вообще вырезает вопросительный знак и знак равенства, а их нужно вывести, подскажите как?

Comment: Забудьте. Это невозможно по определению. Символы ? и = имеют специальное значение в url для задания параметров запроса, и они не могут находиться в строке. И движок тут ни при чём.

Comment: Никак. Но если вы объясните для чего вам это нужно, то, возможно, окажется, что вам нужно не это :) раскройте суть проблемы в общем